# BBPress and Smart Offers wordpress plugins used together

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have installed [bbPress](https://bbpress.org/) and [Smart Offers](http://www.storeapps.org/product/smart-offers/) for a client on his wordpress site. If I use both the following plugins and activate them, I get the following error:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   /wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/common/functions.php
>   on line 1446
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/common/functions.php:1446)
>   in
>   /wp-content/plugins/favorites/app/Bootstrap.php
>   on line 66
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/common/functions.php:1446)
>   in /wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1174

Both the vendors has said it's not their plugin causing the error. I need to get this resolved, and my knowledge of wordpress is limited. Smart Offers says it's not their fault, as it is working without BBPress.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the errors go away if you're using only bbPress, without Smart Offers?

Comment: @BenHarrison, I can run bbPress without errors, or Smart Offers without errors, but not together on the same wordpress installation.